# Android : Thread not passing data to Handler

Tags: java, android, multithreading

I am working on an Android project in which I have to connect to a server, retrieve a list of restaurants and display it in a ListView. The situation is when the app is started, for testing, I am starting another Intent and running a thread inside it. Inside the thread, I am retrieving data from a server which I would like to display it on the ListView. But the handler method which should get the data and display it, is not working. 
Unfortunately I am getting no errors to isolate and deal with the problem, and as passing data between threads is a core function, I am getting lost in the so many methods it calls in between. Kindly have a look what I am doing wrong.

MainActivity class :

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity {

    RestaurantServiceImpl restaurantService = new RestaurantServiceImpl();

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.standortermitteln);
//Below starts the new view
        Intent listScreen = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),RestaurantList.class); 
}
```

RestaurantList.java :

```
  public class RestaurantList extends Activity {

        String url1 = "http://192.168.178.40:8080/restaurant/listing";

        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.restos);

            ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.restaurantList);
            Thread thread = new Thread(new Runnable() {

                @Override
                public void run() {
                    Log.d("Are we in listRestaurants","Checking");
                    try {
                        RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
                        HttpHeaders requestHeaders = new HttpHeaders();
                        requestHeaders.setAccept(Collections.singletonList(new MediaType("application", "json")));
                        HttpEntity<?> requestEntity = new HttpEntity<Object>(requestHeaders);
                        restTemplate.getMessageConverters().add(new GsonHttpMessageConverter());
                        ResponseEntity<Restaurant[]> responseEntity = restTemplate.exchange(url1, HttpMethod.GET, requestEntity, Restaurant[].class);
                        Restaurant[] restaurantList = responseEntity.getBody();
                    for(Restaurant restaurant : restaurantList){
// I am able to print these messages,
                            Log.d(restaurant.getRestaurantName(), "Restaurant name");
                        }
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        Log.d("We are in stacktrace",e.toString());
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            });
            thread.setPriority(android.os.Process.THREAD_PRIORITY_BACKGROUND);
            thread.start();

// I am not reaching here to set the ListView
             Handler messageHandler = new Handler(){
                public void handleMessage(Message message){
                    try {
                        Restaurant[] restaurants = (Restaurant[]) message.obj;
                        for(Restaurant restaurant : restaurants){
                            Log.d(restaurant.getRestaurantName(), "Restaurant name");
                        }
                        if(restaurants.length<1){
                            Log.d("Restaurants from thread are empty"," check");
                        }
                        for(Restaurant restaurant : restaurants){
                            Log.d(restaurant.getRestaurantName(), "Restaurant name in messageHandler");
                        }
                        ArrayAdapter<Restaurant> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(getApplicationContext(),android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,restaurants);
                        listView.setAdapter(adapter);
                    }catch (Exception e){
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            };
        }
    }
```

Comment: use an AsyncTask. btw you are not sending any message to the handler

Comment: @Blackbelt : Thanks. Doing that now. But I would like to send the list of Restaurants not just Message object.

Comment: use an event bus such as https://github.com/greenrobot/EventBus so you can go posting events and listen them from whatever the other participant classes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you are sending the message to the handler from the thread, it will not call the handler. Add following line to your thread.

```
handleMessage.sendMessage(new Message());
```

**Edit:**

Add object

```
Message message =new Message();
message.obj=arrayobject;
```

Comment: Oh...I missed that...Thanks a lot. But how can I send an custom object Array in message? here a list of Restaurants..

Comment: I will mark your answer as worked in 2 mins, for some reason stackoverflow wont allow me now. Thanks, it worked... :-)

Comment: obtainMessage() is leaner than new Message(). For this application it doesn't matter but if you are sending a substantial amount of messages it matters (Less GC)

Answer (score 2):

Add `queueNewRestaurants(restaurantList);` to the end of the first thread.

```
private static final int NEW_RESTAURANTS = 1;

public void queueNewRestaurants(Restaurant[] restaurants) {
    android.os.Message message = messageHandler.obtainMessage(
            NEW_RESTAURANTS,
            restaurants
    );
    message.sendToTarget();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are creating a Handler but never sending anything to it. In this case I would recommend that once you have your restaurantList in your worker thread, you either post a runnable to a Handler that you create as part of your activity being constructed, or you use runOnUiThread.

**Option 1.**

```
public class RestaurantList extends Activity {

    String url1 = "http://192.168.178.40:8080/restaurant/listing";
    Handler mHandler = new Handler();

    ...
    ...
    ...


    Thread thread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                ...
                ...
                ...
                final Restaurant[] restaurantList = responseEntity.getBody();
                mHandler.post(new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {
                        // update UI here
                    }
                });
```

**Option 2.**

call

```
runOnUiThread(new Runnable(.....));
```

instead of mHandler.post(.....)

**Option 3.**

Use an [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html), do the HTTP work in doInBackground() and update your UI in onPostExecute(). Using an AsyncTask you don't have to care about creating any thread at all, it's done for you.

In this particular case I would probably go for option 3.

Answer (score 0):

Except for `Handler`, you also can use java API inside your thread `run()`:

```
runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {

           //communicate with main thread here, send the result data to main thread

        }
    });
```